# Convergence of stochastic process divided by floor.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Assume that $N(t)$ is a stochastic process with positive and integer values. We know that:

$\frac{N(t)}{t} \xrightarrow{\text{P}} c, \hspace{0.5cm} t \rightarrow \infty$

where $c$ is positive and integer valued random variable.
I would like to prove that:
$\frac{[c t]}{N(t)} \xrightarrow{\text{P}} 1$ in a formal way, because it looks intuitively.

Is this attempt even close to the answer?

\begin{align}
P \left( \left| \frac{[c t]}{N(t)} - 1 \right| > \epsilon \right) &= 
P \left( [c t] - N(t) > \epsilon N(t) \right) + P \left( [c t] - N(t) < - \epsilon N(t) \right) \\&\leq P \left( ct + 1 - N(t) > \epsilon N(t) \right) + P \left( ct - 1 - N(t) < -\epsilon N(t) \right)\\ & = P \left( ct - N(t) > \epsilon N(t) - 1 \right) + P \left( ct - N(t) < \epsilon N(t) + 1 \right).
\end{align}

And what can I do now for obtaining the proof?

Comment: Note that $x - 1 \leq [x] \leq x$

Comment: Would you recommend try do it with definition of the convergence in probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it could be simpler to do a reasoning with sequences. It suffices to show that for each sequence $\left(t_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}t_n=+\infty$, the sequence $\left(Y_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ defined by 
$$
Y_n:=\frac{\left[ct_n\right]}{N\left(t_n\right)}
$$
converges to $1$ in probability. We can use the following facts.

1. [If a sequence of positive random variables $\left(Z_n\right)$ converges to $1$ in probability, so does the sequence $\left(1/Z_n\right)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117666/if-x-n-converges-in-probability-to-1-where-does-1-x-n-converge-to)
2. [If the sequences of positive random variables $\left(Z_n\right)$ and $\left(Z'_n\right)$  converges to $1$ in probability, so does $\left(Z_nZ'_n\right)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544449/product-of-random-variables-convergence-in-probability)
3. $\left(\left[ct_n\right]/\left(ct_n\right)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $1$ in probability.